# How to divide Resnet50 model to two parts and then train data in order in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I tried to have get an intermediate feature map of a pre-trained Resnet50 model in pytorch. So i did like this:

```
resnet50_model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

x = torch.ones(16, 3, 224, 224)

m0 = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet50_model.children())[:5])
m1 = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet50_model.children())[5:])
x1 = m0(x)
x2 = m1(x1)
# Do something with x1
```

But then the program complained that:

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [32768 x 1], m2: [2048 x 1000] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:41
```

The error seems because the shape of `x1` is incompatible with `m1()`. But in Resnet50 they are connected each other and there is no gap between them. Can anyone help me with that? How should I correct the code?

Comment: I think the problem is with something you are doing with x2. Probably you are using some loss function to compute the loss (I get this impression because 1000 is the output dimension of resnet

Comment: @KaranDwivedi No in fact I didn't do anything with x2, the line `x2 = m1(x1)` is the last line of my code

Comment: [`ResNet`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/resnet.html#resnet) performs a flatten operation which isn't a child layer during forward pass. You'll need to do the same.

Comment: @jodag You're right! Thank you so much!

Comment: @anArkitek would you mind please posting the solution?